# Referencing the WebEngine from one .java file to another

Tags: reference, javafx-2, javafx

Here is the file `ClientArea.java` (located in folder *demoapp*) which uses a WebEngine object.

```
public class ClientArea implements Initializable {
    public WebEngine engine;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        engine = browser.getEngine();
        engine.load("about:blank");
    }
}
```

I want to reference it to another file (`Undecorator.java`), located in folder  *insidefx.undecorator*

How can I make this reference?

Answer (score 1):

I solve similar problems as follows: In the place where you load the fxml file, you can get any element of the controller and provide its reference to the other controller.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());

fxmlLoader.setLocation(...); // set a URL for the ClientArea.fxml
try {
   fxmlLoader.load();
} catch (IOException ex) {
   ...
}
ClientArea cacontroller = (ClientArea) fxmlLoader.getController();

WebEngine engine = cacontroller.getEngine(); // add a getter method in ClientArea

fxmlLoader.setLocation(...); // set a URL for the Undecorator.fxml
try {
   fxmlLoader.load();
} catch (IOException ex) {
   ...
}
Undecorator ucontroller = (Undecorator) fxmlLoader.getController();
ucontroller.setEngine(engine); // add a setter method in Undecorator
```

Comment: What do you mean by "an example with WebEngine"? The example above is "with WebEngine". Actually, you can reference any Object (belonging to some other controller) with this trick.